# SQL Shifting 2 columns a row down with rollover

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I am currently trying to manipulate a table in SQL Server.

The following table is an example:

```
Id  |  PrimaryId  |  PrimaryMail  |  SecondaryId  |  SecondaryMail
1.     1.        email1@something.  5.          email2@something
2.     2.        email3@something.  6.          email4@something
3.     3.        email5@something.  7.          email6@something
4.     4.        email7@something.  8.          email8@something
```

I want it to become the following:

```
Id  |  PrimaryId  |  PrimaryMail  |  SecondaryId  |  SecondaryMail
1.     1.        email1@something.  6.          email4@something
2.     2.        email3@something.  7.          email6@something
3.     3.        email5@something.  8.          email8@something
4.     4.        email7@something.  5.          email2@something
```

I found a similar question on here but the person did not want to use joins and the actual thing I am after is the rollover mechanic that makes either the first row become the last row or the last row the first row depending on what direction you shift the columns.

I already have the following code that makes the items in the columns go up by 1 row. But the last row currently stays the same and I lose the data from the first row.

```
--Calculate the height of the table
DECLARE @CouplesCount AS INT
SELECT @CouplesCount = COUNT(*) FROM Couples

--Shift the Secondary users down one row
UPDATE c1
SET c1.SecondaryId = c2.SecondaryId, c1.SecondaryMail = c2.SecondaryMail
FROM Couples c1 join
     Couples c2
     on c2.Id = c1.Id + 1
     WHERE c1.CouplesId <= @CouplesCount - 1

SELECT * FROM Couples
```

Thank in advance to anyone that can help me.
p.s. I cannot use MySQL code

Comment: What if there are more than two rows in the table, which logic do you want? It might help if you could expand your data and results with a few more rows.

Comment: I edited the amount of rows. I basically want it to loop around.

Answer (score 4):

If the version of SQL Server that you use is SQL Server 2012 or later, you can use window functions [`LEAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

`LEAD` returns the values from the "next" row (as defined by the `ORDER BY` clause). It will return `NULL` for the last row, because there is no "next" row there.

So, for the last row we need to return the first row, which can be done by the `FIRST_VALUE`.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @Couples TABLE (
    Id int, PrimaryId int, PrimaryMail nvarchar(100), 
    SecondaryId int, SecondaryMail nvarchar(100));

INSERT INTO @Couples VALUES
(1, 1, 'email1@something', 5, 'email2@something'),
(2, 2, 'email3@something', 6, 'email4@something'),
(3, 3, 'email5@something', 7, 'email6@something'),
(4, 4, 'email7@something', 8, 'email8@something');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    C.Id
    ,C.PrimaryId
    ,C.PrimaryMail
    ,ISNULL(LEAD(C.SecondaryId) OVER (ORDER BY C.Id),
        FIRST_VALUE(C.SecondaryId) OVER (ORDER BY C.Id))
    AS SecondaryId
    ,ISNULL(LEAD(C.SecondaryMail) OVER (ORDER BY C.Id),
        FIRST_VALUE(C.SecondaryMail) OVER (ORDER BY C.Id))
     AS SecondaryMail
FROM
    @Couples AS C
;
```

**Result**

```
+----+-----------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
| Id | PrimaryId |   PrimaryMail    | SecondaryId |  SecondaryMail   |
+----+-----------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
|  1 |         1 | email1@something |           6 | email4@something |
|  2 |         2 | email3@something |           7 | email6@something |
|  3 |         3 | email5@something |           8 | email8@something |
|  4 |         4 | email7@something |           5 | email2@something |
+----+-----------+------------------+-------------+------------------+
```

**Update**

If you need to actually change the table itself, it is easy to do as well, just wrap the query in a CTE and update it.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        C.Id
        ,C.PrimaryId
        ,C.PrimaryMail
        ,C.SecondaryId
        ,C.SecondaryMail
        ,ISNULL(LEAD(C.SecondaryId) OVER (ORDER BY C.Id),
            FIRST_VALUE(C.SecondaryId) OVER (ORDER BY C.Id))
        AS NewSecondaryId
        ,ISNULL(LEAD(C.SecondaryMail) OVER (ORDER BY C.Id),
            FIRST_VALUE(C.SecondaryMail) OVER (ORDER BY C.Id))
         AS NewSecondaryMail
    FROM
        @Couples AS C
)
UPDATE CTE
SET
    SecondaryId = NewSecondaryId
    ,SecondaryMail = NewSecondaryMail
;

SELECT * FROM @Couples ORDER BY Id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for an answer @Vladimir Baranov! My level is sadly still to low on here to the point where you can't see my upvote.

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer, if you find it useful. It should be pretty easy to get enough reputation to upvote. You need  only 15. Just write a good answer for  somebody's question and get an upvote. Or suggest few good edits to other questions.